How to test a Quarkus application with JUnit 4?
I’m porting an application to Quarkus, and am now updating its tests to use Quarkus as well.
I could port successfully the JUnit 5 tests using @QuarkusTest and @TestHTTPResource:
package com.example.project;

import io.quarkus.test.common.http.TestHTTPResource;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.net.URL;

@QuarkusTest
public class JUnit5Test {
  @TestHTTPResource
  URL url;

  @Test
  public void sampleJunit5Test() {
    Assertions.assertNotNull(url); // ✅ Passes
  }
}

However, doing the same thing on a JUnit 4 doesn’t work:
package com.example.project;

import io.quarkus.test.common.http.TestHTTPResource;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.net.URL;

@QuarkusTest
public class JUnit4Test {
  @TestHTTPResource
  URL url;

  @Test
  public void sampleJunit4Test() {
    Assert.assertNotNull(url); // ❌ java.lang.AssertionError
  }
}

In my situation, I can’t port these JUnit 4 tests to JUnit 5. How can I run these tests with Quarkus?

Why don’t you migrate to junit 5 ?

@Serkan In my case, the tests extend some JUnit 4 test classes that are located in another codebase that I don’t control.

I feel you that this is difficult, but do you think you could rewrite the functionality of the other codebase in a module that you control? Or, write an adapter, so that you can use this functionality from JUnit5? The JUnit5 extensions are very-very simple to implement and at the same time powerful enough to (probably) suit your needs. Bottom line: I would try porting the functionality to JUnit5. If you can disclose specifics (in a different question), maybe we could help further.

JUnit 4 is not supported by Quarkus

To run JUnit 4 tests with Quarkus, you need to use the Quarkus QuarkusTestExtension specifically designed to support JUnit 4, as JUnit 4 does not natively support some of the annotations and functionality that JUnit 5 provides through @QuarkusTest.
